# How to find Android phone running 64-bit operating system for software testing purposes?

Tags: android, testing, 64-bit

While many phones have 64-bit ARM processors, they all seem to be running  Android 32-bit operating systems.  Are any phones running 64-bit Android?

After testing on a 64-bit Android emulator, I now need a real Android device running a 64-bit operating system to test Bluetooth 4.0 classic communications.

My app uses native code and JNI.  It is not pure java.

**Background**: Starting August 1, 2019 Google requires all apps published on Google Play to support Android 64-bit.

- https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

> Starting August 1, 2019, your apps published on Google Play will need
>   to support 64-bit architectures

I cannot find a way to search for and locate Android devices running 64-bit Android.

**What I Have Learned:**

- ARM64 hardware does NOT mean the device is running Android 64-bit, only that it is capable.
- Example: I purchased a Moto G7; ARM64 and 4GB RAM, it runs **32-bit Android**.
- A Samsung S7 has ARM64 and only 1.5GB RAM but *DOES* run **64-bit Android**.
- Fact: RAM > 4GB is not addressable by 32-bit Android. This is not a useful indicator of 64-bit Android because all affordable Android devices have 4GB or less RAM.

The only solution is to have access to the device before purchase or ask a friend and get same exact model.

I have reports from coworkers that Pixel1 and Pixel2 run 64-bit Android.  I cannot make a blanket statement that all Pixels run 64-bit Android, but it may be true.

Comment: How can I identify a 64-bit Android phone before purchase? I know how to determine after purchase. I need a 64-bit Android testing device. Purchasing a phone with a 64-bit ARM CPU does not guarantee it is running a 64-bit Android OS, only that it is capable,

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I have a sizable body of stats for user Android devices. The report provides the current CPU architecture from the JNI library in the same logic as below. The stats also have the contents of `Build.MODEL` - about 2000 distinct lines for ARM64. The list is too large for a SO answer - so I published it elsewhere. [Enjoy.](https://rathertech.blogspot.com/2019/06/those-are-sixty-four.html)

There's no guarantee, though. There's a chance one mobile carrier would ship a model with the 32-bit OS while another sells them with the 64-bit one.

Some lines would take a bit of Googling. The way device vendors spread their signature over the fields of `Build` is anything but uniform.

---

If you have a JNI component, and you build it for all architectures, introduce a conditional based on the current compilation target, and interrogate it from the Java side.

```
extern "C" jboolean JNIEXPORT Java_com_acme_MyClass_Is64(JNIEnv *jni, jobject cl)
{
#if defined(__aarch64__) || defined(__amd64__)
    return JNI_TRUE;
#else
    return JNI_FALSE;
#endif
}
```

Ignoring MIPS64, which isn't even supported in the modern versions of NDK. On the Java side, it would be available as:

```
package com.acme;
class MyClass
{
    public static native boolean Is64();
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there may be some device specs that would indicate a device must be running 64-bit Android OS.  Manufactures do not tell you.  I think there are none.  A Samsung S7 with ARM64 and 1.5GB RAM is running 64-bit.  My Moto G7 has ARM64, 4GB RAM, yet runs 32-bit Android.  However, variants of the same Moto G7 have  reported to be running 64-bit Android.  In 2019, the only way to know if a phone is running 64-bit Android is to have access to it *before* purchase.  There may be some generalizations that *could* be true like all Google Pixel devices run 64-bit Android.

Comment: Judging by native crash reports I'm getting, there are 64-bit models out there. Now, to get some stats from that. Crash reports are not easy to run queries against.